# Will initializing disk remove my files on my external hdd?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, mac

This hdd is for my mac so its formatted for mac. But suddenly its not showing on my mac.

So I tried windows and its being read. I cant open it since it says i need to "initialize" it.

How do I go about this without losing data? And also be read by my mac again?

Comment: "not showing on my mac" where? Disk Utility? Desktop? Does the Mac say it needs Initialising? Windows will, because it cannot read Mac disks by default. If you initialise it in Windows a) you will not be able to read it on the Mac at all & b) you will remove any simple access to the files & be down to recovery software.

Comment: Not showing on finder, disk utility, anywhere. It shows an alert after 5 minutes saying " the disk you inserted was not readable by this computer". Mac doesnt say it needs initialising. Nothing happens except that alert msg. Can i at least get the files on the hdd so i can back them up?

Comment: Not with that message, no. You have 2 options - see if relocating the drive to another enclosure will re-enable it. If that fails, your best bet is probably a professional data recovery company. Note that the entire idea of a backup is to make it **before** you need it. You're now past the 'backup' stage & into the 'emergency data recovery' stage.

Comment: Great! Ill just go to someone that will repair this then. What do you mean by relocating the drive to another enclosure?

Comment: I mean physically remove the drive from its original enclosure & put it into a brand new one. SATA adaptor docks/enclosures are pretty cheap these days. That will at least test whether the drive has died, or the SATA connector. 20 bucks vs many hundreds for data recovery.

Comment: WAIT. I can initialize the disk on my mac! IT shows on the alert that says "the disk you inserted etc. etc." Should i do that!?

Comment: No. You'll just make things worse.

Comment: Does this mean my hd is toasted already cause both devices say i need to initialize them?

Comment: I've already described your two potential scenarios. Either the enclosure is toast, or the HD is. One costs about 20 bucks to test, the other several hundred.